# Add late vote badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

On stackoverflow, I think there should be a badge for voting late on questions and answers, since that would encourage more voting. One area this would be useful in is people searching for programming on any search engine, and finding stackoverflow there, and finding a useful question/answer.

The badge could be something like this - Late voter-100 votes on questions that have been inactive for more than two weeks

Comment: Lack of voting is not a problem we have... Why should "late" voting be encouraged at all?

Comment: Wouldn't this discourage people from voting on new questions while chasing the badge?

Comment: @hammar voting on new questions and voting on old questions aren't mutually exclusive

Comment: @RichardTingle - It is if you consider vote limits. Every old question you vote on is one new one less that you _can_ vote on that day (IIRC 30 votes per day limit?)

Comment: I suppose that is true (for whatever percentage hit the limit), still rebalancing the votes towards older questions which are currently underrepresented doesn't sound like a bad thing

Comment: I want people to vote because the question / answer deserves a vote, **not** because they are chasing some badge.

Comment: But there are already vote badges, electorate, etc

Comment: This would however encorage voting on 30 random old posts each day for 4 days though

Comment: But I agree with the OP, late answers dont get enough attention. For those interested in upvotes an answer to a new "fix my code" question will be far more profitable than an old but more widely useful question.

Comment: @RichardTingle: But he's not talking about *late answers*, he's talking about voting on *inactive* questions and answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is already covered by the **Civic Duty** badge. The key thing here that improves search results is the fact that *you voted*. Whether you voted when the question or answer was first posted or voted a year later doesn't really matter. All that matters is you cast your vote, and the community now has a [however slightly] better experience on the site.

There's no need to encourage users to vote on older content when we already encourage users to vote in general. The age of the question or answer really shouldn't even matter; only the quality and helpfulness should.